# How to find out the currently used version of VirtualBox guest additions on Windows using cmd?

Tags: windows, virtualbox, cmd.exe, guest-additions

I would like to get the version of VirtualBox guest additions that are actually used on a Windows Server 2016 machine.

I tried this command

```
c:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox Guest Additions>VBoxControl.exe --version
5.1.12r112440
```

but the problem is that I updated the guest additions several times and there are other folders containing different version of VirtualBox and thus of the VBoxControl.exe too, e.g.

```
c:\virtual_box_guest_additions>VBoxControl.exe --version
5.1.22r115126
```

The version actually in use is shown in the tray icon.
How can I get this version using a batch script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get path to currently running VBoxService:

```
sc qc VBoxService | FIND /I "BINARY_PATH_NAME"
```

Then use this command to get version:

```
<path from above command\VBoxService.exe> --version
```

In my case: "C:\Windows\System32\VBoxService.exe --version"

Outputs: 5.1.28r117968

Answer (score 1):

The round about way is to visit task manager when VirtualBox Manager is running.
**Right-Click** on **VirtualBox Manager** > **Left-Click** on **open file location**.
In the File Explorer navigated to **Left-Click doc** > **Left-Click UserManual.pdf** and if you can open it in Adobe Reader should have the VirtualBox version listed on the title page.